# Allow function calls only in special context

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to write a class that only allows certain methods to be called in a lambda of one function.

Basically, I want to achieve similar behaviour to how you can only call suspend functions in a suspend context.

Right now the closest I can get is this.

```
class MyClass {
   fun runCommands(block: CommandContext.() -> Unit) {
      // do prep work
      block.invoke(commandContext)
      // do cleanup work
   }

   val commandContext = CommandContext()
   inner class CommandContext {
      fun commandFunc() {} // only callable from the lambda
   }
}
```

The issues I'm having with this is I can't make CommandContext private so you could always make your own instance and run the command externally. It is also unnecessary for it to be instantiatable but I can't make an "inner object."

Any ideas on how to do this cleaner?

Answer (score 2):

Outer scope should know that there is a `commandFunc()` method in `CommandContext` class (and that this class actually exists). That's why it can't be private. But you can encapsulate its implementation, effectively making it private, keeping public only its interface:

```kotlin
interface CommandContext {
    fun commandFunc()
}

class MyClass {
    fun runCommands(block: CommandContext.() -> Unit) {
        // do prep work
        block.invoke(CommandContextImpl)
        // do cleanup work
    }

    private object CommandContextImpl : CommandContext {
        override fun commandFunc() {} //actual implementation
    }
}

//Usage:
fun main() {
    MyClass().runCommands { commandFunc() }
}
```

Comment: It's probably more sensible as an interface than an abstract class. That's how CoroutineContext is defined. And there's no reason to assign an object to a property.

Comment: Indeed, interface is more suitable here that abstract class, it at least will make code more concise! Thanks, will edit my answer! 
But I didn't get why object shouldn't be assigned to property? Inlining it will be less performant - it will be recreated (and then collected by GC) on each `runCommands` method call.

Comment: I mean it doesn't have to be an anonymous class. This is more concise, or at least less noisy: Instead of `private val commandContext = object :` you can use `private object CommandContextImpl :`.